# "Missing click tag" despite Google Ad Manager tap area exit event

Tags: html, google-ad-manager, google-web-designer

In [Google Web Designer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Designer), I want to create an HTML5 ad.

I added a tap area and set its "*Metrics ID*" to "*clickTag*":

[image: Tap area clickTag]

**Problem**: When importing the resulting ZIP into [Google Ad Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ad_Manager), I get an error:

[image: Missing click tag. Add a valid click tag or exit function before uploading the creative to Ad Manager.]

What am I doing wrong?

By the way:

- Google Web Designer does not generate `var clickTag`, which is probably the problem.
- The same message appears with [this official template](http://gwd-template://Standard%20Banner%20Static) ([web](https://www.richmediagallery.com/create/templates#tplGeneratorPath:inpage%2F300x250%2Fimage%2Fborder%3Dfalse~)) even though it contains an exit event.
- I know it is not Ad Manager, but [Campaign Manager's official documentation](https://support.google.com/dcm/answer/3145300#40) describes what I did, stressing that "*No custom code is required"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**: you need to use the right 'ad environment' to be able to upload ad Web Designer creative in Ad Manager.

When you create your file, chose "Display & Video 360". You should also be able to switch the ad environment :

1. Go to "File"
2. Then "Ad Environment"
3. Click on "Display & Video 360"

See [here](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/7053700?hl=en) for more details about the ad environment.

**Second** : make sure your creative follow the creative & click tag guidelines detailed [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7046799?hl=en).

In your case :
simply erase "Metrics ID" value or change its value to something else
do not set any URL up (it will be done in Ad Manager when trafficked)
amend the html as per the following example :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=300,height=250">
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickTag = "YOUR_DESTINATION_URL"; </script>
</head>
<a href="javascript:void(window.open(clickTag))">
<img src="images/dclk.png" border=0>
</a>
</html>
```

Normally, this should allow Ad Manager to recognize your creative clicktag.

Comment: It is already "Display & Video 360", unfortunately. That's the default.

Comment: Allright, I edited my answer to add more details on how to make Ad Manager html5 creative compliant.